# Ajax reload input value and table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I use ajax to send the values ​​of my input Checkbox to my controller.
I get the data from my database.

However, view side I only see the result in DEBUG mode

I think my problem is that my TABLE does NOT RELOAD.

Someone can give me a helping hand why I do not have the result in my view, only in debuG mode

CHECKBOX

```
Input = "check" type = "checkbox" name = "_ id []" id = "checkbox" checked value = "1">
Input = "check" type = "checkbox" name = "_ id []" id = "checkbox" checked value = "2">
```

CONTROLLER

```
 Public function index ()
    {
        If ($ this-> input-> post ('c_id')) {
            $ Get_id = $ this-> input-> post ('c_id');
            $ Groupby_id = $ this-> model-> group_list ($ get_id);
        }
        $ Data ['groups'] = $ groupby_id;
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
Public function gr_list ($ cp_id)
    {
        Return $ this-> db-> select ("*")
        -> where_in ("cp_id", $ company_id)
        -> get ("grs");
    }
```

MY VIEW TABLE

```
<Table class = "table-striped">
            <Thead>
              <Tr>
                <Th> Groups </th>
                <Th> This Wek </th>
                <Th>% Chg vs LY </th>
              </Tr>
            </Thead>
            <Tbody>
            <? Php foreach ($ groups-> result () as $ gp):?>

              <Tr>
                <Td> <a href="#"> <? Php echo $ gp-> group_name?> </a> </td>
                <Td> <? Php echo $ gp-> amount?></td>
                <Td> <a href="#"> <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"> </a> </ span> <? Php echo $ gp-> compvalue?
              </ Tr>
            <? Php endforeach; ?>
            </Tbody>
   </Table>
```

AJAX

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
      var values = [];
      $.each($('input:checked'),function(index,input){
      values.push(input.value);
      });
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              async: true,
              cache: false,
              url: "<?php echo site_url('index') ?>",
              data: { c_id:values }
          }).done(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          })
          e.preventDefault();
      }
      });

      $("#checkAll").click(function () {
          $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
      });
```

Comment: What do you mean - debug mode? Developer tools in the browser? What browser do you use? There are some issues with IE9 and using console

Comment: Yes when i use chrome developer tools console  i see my table with informations but in my website i don't see

Comment: so `data` in `done` function contains entire table html? You have to replace you current table with the new `data`, like this `$('.table-striped').replaceWith(data)` BUT if table or its elements had js handlers - you have to add them again

Comment: Please! @Grin you can have an idea how to build total html table in done function please!

Comment: what do you have in `data` variable?

Comment: data variable {group_name, amount, compvalue}

Comment: is it array in json format? or one entry?

Comment: non i get data from my database  $this-> model-> group_list ($get_id); with $_POST(c_id), no return in json format

Comment: but you can see something in console? plz  add screenshot with console output

Comment: I get the result perfectly as I wish. Only the design of my html page is deformed

Comment: So I would like to base the <tbody> </ tbody>
in the done function

Comment: you can use foreach and build your tbody html using string concatenation and then append result to the tbody but i need to know what your data looks like if you want that i write the working example for you

Comment: i have foreach in my view, please can you check my code to see....

Comment: please @Gin  can you give me the working example please

Comment: in your example you are missing `></td>` here `<? Php echo $ gp-> compvalue?` is it just a copypaste mistake?

Comment: @Grin Yes it's copypaste mistake the real is <?php echo $gp->comparevalue ?>%</td>

Comment: here is an example how you can build the tbody after getting data from the server https://jsfiddle.net/grin/94adbgs5/1/

Comment: thank you @Grin. i maked like this  https://jsfiddle.net/kimoudev/4j4Lw3sa/ but nothing